# Laravel show errors if request form validation fails

Tags: php, rest, validation, laravel, request

I'm making a REST API that should validate data entry from the user, to achieve that, I made a `Request` class that has the `rules` function that it should do the validations.

#### Request class

```
class StoreUpdateQuestionRequest extends Request {

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        $method = $this->method();
        $rules = [
            'question' => 'required|min:10|max:140',
            'active' => 'boolean',
        ];

        return $method !== 'GET' || $method !== 'DELETE' ? $rules : [];
    }
}
```

So, in the controller, when I try to run an endpoint which it fires the validations, it does work, it fails when it's has to, but it doesn't show me the errors as I expect, even though I defined the error messages in the `messages` function contained in the `Request` class, instead of showing me that errors, it redirects me to a location. Which sometimes is the result of a request I made before or it runs the `/` route, weird.

#### Controller function

```
public function store(StoreUpdateQuestionRequest $request) {

    $question = new Question;
    $question->question = $request->question;
    $question->active = $request->active;

    if($question->save()) {

        $result = [
            'message' => 'A question has been added!',
            'question' => $question,
        ];

        return response()->json($result, 201);
    }

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do print_r($request->all());die; what it returns ?

Comment: @HimanshuRaval, tried to run that line of code in the first statement of the store function, gets redirected to a route that is not implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make this work, you have to add an extra header to your request:

```
Accept: application/json
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use controller based validation as described in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#manually-creating-validators

```
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'question' => 'required|min:10|max:140',
            'active' => 'boolean',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors());
        }


        //other 
    }
```